# Couldn't remove list from list of dictionaries based on a set of ids

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below list of dictionaries,

```
id_list=[22,24]
res=[{'st': 20, 'companies': [{'cname': 'BMW'}, {'cname': 'Tesla'} ], 'id': 20}, 
     {'st': 60, 'companies': [{'cname': 'Benz'}, {'cname': 'Audi'} ], 'id': 21}, 
     {'st': 20, 'companies': [{'cname': 'Volvo'}, {'cname': 'Tesla'} ], 'id': 24}]
```

Am trying to remove list from the res list of dictionaries for which if id in res matches with the id_list values.

I would like to have the result as

```
res=[{'st': 20, 'companies': [{'cname': 'BMW'}, {'cname': 'Tesla'} ], 'id': 20}, 
     {'st': 60, 'companies': [{'cname': 'Benz'}, {'cname': 'Audi'} ], 'id': 21}]
```

How can I do that ?

I tried using below, it doesn't work

```
data = []
for g, items in res:
    items = [{k: v for k, v in item.items() if k not in id_list} for item in items]
    data.append({ 'id': g[0],'st':g[1],'companies':g[2] })
print(data)
```

Either a new list or existing one is also fine for the final output.

Comment: Your current code does `if k not in id_list`, but `k` in this case is `'id'`, not `20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to do it as :

```
new_lsit = [i for i in res if i['id'] not in id_list]
```

Treating the dictionaries stores in the `list` as elements and checking the condition without recreating new dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda d: d['id'] not in id_list and d, res)
```

or

```
filter(lambda d: d['id'] not in id_list, res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do  `for g, items in res` because res is a list `(for dict_ in res)`,
You can check if `id` is in `id_list`, then append it to data list.

```
data = []
for d in res:
    if d['id'] not in  id_list:
            data.append(d)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 1):

Other people have shown you a way without explicit iteration. Since you were initially iterating over the list here is a way to achieve the same with iteration.

```
id_list=[22,24]
res=[{'st': 20, 'companies': [{'cname': 'BMW'}, {'cname': 'Tesla'} ], 'id': 20}, 
     {'st': 60, 'companies': [{'cname': 'Benz'}, {'cname': 'Audi'} ], 'id': 21}, 
     {'st': 20, 'companies': [{'cname': 'Volvo'}, {'cname': 'Tesla'} ], 'id': 24}]
data = []
for item in res:
        if item.get('id') not in id_list: 
                data.append(item)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!